# Convert three digit currency code to locale for money_format?

Tags: php, currency, money-format

I have an array as such

```
'USD' => 'US Dollar',
'EUR' => 'Euro',
'GBP' => 'British Pound',
'INR' => 'Indian Rupee',
```

I would like to take a given amount, say 100000.00 and convert it into the correct money format based on the array key.

For example, I'd like to do something like `custom_money_format('INR','100000.00')` and have it return the correct format, including the currency symbol if possible, but if not, that's fine.

To do this, I know I can use [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) but I would need the right local code to use, and I don't know how to get that dynamically based on the currency code. Is there a list of codes that I can use?

Comment: There may be multiple formats for a given currency; Consider that EUR is valid across 19 different countries, which may have differing decimal separators, for example. The other hint would be that the first two characters of an [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) code are the same two characters of a ISO 3166, so it's just a case of determining the language to display in (see also ISO 639)

Answer (score 0):

You find your answer here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

```
<?php
echo NumberFormatter::formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, 'USD');
echo NumberFormatter::formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, 'EUR');
// et cetera
```

Therefor u have to use `PECL` php- extension.

Comment: But your locale isn't changing at all, so how is the money_format actually using the currency code in this example, it seems all you're doing is putting different symbols, and not formatting the currency different.

Comment: you can format your currency per type yourself, I showed how to switch between different currency formatting.

Comment: That's the point of my question, to find out how to format the money automatically based on the currency code, not how to make my own function to do it. There are almost 170 currency codes in my list, I'd like this automated. Thanks for your attempt though.

Comment: I really appreciate you coming back to this to help. IT seems that according to php.net I still need to define the locale first via `$fmt = numfmt_create( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );` or something similar, and that the method you gave as an example is missing the first argument of the `NumberFormatter object`. I tried your code anyway, but my server doesn't seem to have PECL installed. You can leave this alone if you'd like, as it seems impossible without first specifying a locale code, such as `en_US` in order to format properly.